# Conflict between Pandas and Unittest?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-unittest

Consider the following block of code (developed inside a Jupyter notebook), for which it is expected that an `AssertionError` is raised because a `UserWarning` is not triggered:

```
%%writefile Game/tests/tests.py
import unittest
import pandas as pd

class TestGame(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_getters(self):
        print('Just before the critical line.')
        with self.assertWarns(UserWarning):
            print('Just testing...')

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestGame)
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

For those unfamiliar with jupyter notebooks, the first line simply exports all following lines into the specified file.

Now if I execute the command:

```
python3 tests.py
```

from the terminal (I am using Python 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04), I get a `Runtime Error` - the stack trace follows:

```
Just before the critical line:
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_getters (__main__.TestGame)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 8, in test_getters
    with self.assertWarns(UserWarning):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 225, in __enter__
    for v in sys.modules.values():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Obviously the results are not as expected. However, I notice that either of the following options gets the expected results.

1. Commenting out the first line with `%%writefile ...` and running the code snippet with the Jupyter notebook (which uses the same python interpreter).
2. Commenting out the `import pandas as pd` line and running from terminal with the previously given command.

Does anyone understand what's going on here?

For reference, the relevant lines in `case.py` in the `unittest` module are

```
for v in sys.modules.values():
    if getattr(v, '__warningregistry__', None):
        v.__warningregistry__ = {}
```

which would seem to be benign code (which I would also presume is tested enough to say that it's not the source of the problem).

Comment: Did you ever manage to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: No, I had to use a work around :(

Comment: I can't replicate this. Also, the description of the problem is convoluted and unhelpful the way you wrote it. What happens is that you have different behaviors when _running the code as a script_ (tests.py) and when running the code within a notebook.

Comment: And the error seems to be that `sys.modules` is being modified during the loop. I have no idea what is causing this. Please post your workaround if possible

Comment: Sorry, far too long ago to track it down.

Comment: what happens if you comment the last 2 lines and run the test from command line as follows:  `python -m unittest tests.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been filed on [Python's bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue29620).

> The problem is in the iteration over `sys.modules` in `unittest.case._AssertWarnsContext.__enter__()` and accessing every module's `__warningregistry__` attribute. On this access, the module-like objects may perform arbitrary actions including importing of further modules which extends `sys.modules`.

[`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) is a dict mapping module names to loaded modules.

This problem is difficult to reproduce because there's "[something platform dependent](https://bugs.python.org/issue29620#msg323821)" about how the test runner orders the tests.